# Why does the following code print "0 1 2 3"?

Tags: java

in this code im confused as to why it prints out "0 1 2 3" instead of "3 2 1 0"

```
    int y = 3;
    String s = " ";
    while (y>-1)
    {
        s = y + " " + s;
        y--;
    }
    System.out.print(s);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I've been up for a while and can't really think of another word. I'll try not to do it next time.

Comment: If you run this with a debugger, you'll see immediately what's happening.

Answer (score 6):

```
s = y + " " + s;
```

adds y at the front of the string so:

```
s = 3 
s = 2 3
s = 1 2 3
s = 0 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
step 1:
s = 3

step 2:
s = 2 3;

step 3:
s = 1 2 3
```

like wise in every loop y's value is added to the starting point of the string s

Answer (score 0):

This is because you prepend the newest value to the string. If you want the output to be "3 2 1 0" you should change your line from

```
s = y + " " + s;
```

to

```
s = s + " " + y;
```